# Why does my syntax highlighting disappear after so many splits?

Tags: vimrc, syntax-highlighting, split

I can successfully run `:sp *filename*` several times per vim session, but after a seemingly-random number of splits (5-10) all future splits will no longer have syntax highlighting until I fully quit vim in that terminal. Can be quite annoying as I will have to remember all the files I have open in that session before restarting vim.

To clarify, I am not splitting the current screen between 5-10 files; I am using `:sp` a few times, `:q` to close some windows, `:sp` again, etc. When syntax highlighting starts to fail I might only have 2 or 3 files currently split.

Using `:e` to reload does not help this issue.

I have a pretty simple .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.svp,*.svh,*.sv,*.v,*.vh so ~/.vim/syntax/verilog_systemverilog.vim                                                                                                                    
syntax enable
se ic              
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab
set splitbelow 
set splitright 
set mouse=a           
set textwidth=0
set wrapmargin=0
set laststatus=2
set number    
set wildmenu   
set cursorline 
set cursorcolumn
nnoremap J gJ
set background=light
colorscheme solarized
```

Comment: See if bumping up `'redrawtime'` helps.

Comment: Good suggestion, what is the default for this value as I have never used it before?

Comment: The default value is in the help page. `:h 'rdt'` (And surely what your current setting is if you've never used it before.)

Comment: do you open those `svp`, `svh`, `sv`, etc verilog files? If so what is in `verilog_systemverilog.vim`?